# Adding nginx to my dockerized Django application

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have successfully added gunicorn to my Dockerized Django application.  I'm having trouble adding nginx to the mix.  The nginx server exits almost immediately.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
      build: 
          context: .
          args:
            HTTP_PROXY: http://amec.zscaler.company.com:9480
            HTTPS_PROXY: http://amec.zscaler.company.com:9480
      image: django_web 
      container_name: django_web  
      expose: 
        - "8000"
  nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      ports:
        - 1337:80
      depends_on:
        - web
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ARG HTTP_PROXY
ARG HTTPS_PROXY

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN useradd user
USER user

CMD ["gunicorn", "django_web.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here's my nginx/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Here's nginx.conf:

```
upstream django_web{
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_web/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Command to build and run everything:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.cambridge.yml up -d
```

next command:

```
sudo docker ps -a
    
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
16f4651047ec        django_nginx       "python3"                20 seconds ago      Exited (0) 18 seconds ago                 django_nginx_1
03a460153a9c        django_web         "gunicorn Django.…"      21 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds               8000/tcp            django_web
```

When I run `sudo docker exec -ti 16f4651047ec ping web` I get positive responses.

After a new build, and I run: `sudo docker logs 16f4651047ec`  I get:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration 

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ 

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh 

10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 

10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

After trying to browse to `http://my-ip:1337/` , and I run: `sudo docker logs 16f4651047ec`  I get the same as above plus this one line:

```
161.88.207.220 - - [23/Jul/2020:13:29:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
p
```

After trying to browse to `http://my-ip:1337/get_my_item/` , and I run: `sudo docker logs 16f4651047ec`  I get the same as above plus this:

```
161.88.207.220 - - [23/Jul/2020:13:29:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/07/23 13:33:29 [error] 29#29: *3 "/usr/share/nginx/html/get_my_item/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 161.88.207.220, server: localhost, request: "GET /get_my_item/ HTTP/1.1", host: "10.228.91.5:1337"
161.88.207.220 - - [23/Jul/2020:13:33:29 +0000] "GET /get_my_item/ HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building your nginx image `FROM python:3.6`

Here's a simple nginx:alpine Dockerfile example:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: You said in the post that your nginx/Dockerfile looks like this: 'FROM python:3.6'. Basically you are using a **python** docker image in the attempt to start a **nginx** proxy. Perhaps this is just a silly typo?

Comment: If your nginx Dockerfile is `FROM python:3.6`, you will just have a python runtime in the container that's 'crushing'. How could an nginx be launched without nginx installed.

Comment: To troubleshoot, list all your containers: `docker ps -a`, copy the container ID that is not behaving as you want and run `docker logs <your-container-id>`. Additionally you can use the `docker inspect <your-container-id>` to get more info about the container

Comment: Your proxy pass is `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1` it should be `proxy_pass http://django`

Comment: Ah, missed that as well, thanks. Now when I browse to localhost:1337 I get to the Welcome to nginx page not my web app. Apparently I missed some other configuration but I have no idea what.

Comment: As @DevarshiSathiya said, instead of `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1` you need the name that resolves to your web server

Comment: In this case, the name of your web server is the same as the name of the container that is running the Django app

Comment: In docker there's an internal resolver that resolves the name of the containers to the IPs of the containers.

Comment: After spinning up the containers with docker compose-up, just do a `docker service ls`, `docker ps`. Connect into the nginx container using `docker exec -ti <nginx-container-id>` and try to ping the Django container by its name. According to the compose file, if you `ping web`, on the nginx, you should receive a reply from one of the Django containers that is behind the web service

Comment: Added results from docker logs command in original post.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my nginx:alpine Dockerfile to this

```
FROM nginx:alpine 
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf COPY
nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```